# inputting multiple rows in a textbox and displaying each value in a different row of a single column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to input multiple rows in a textbox and display each value in a different row of a single column in excel, My code inputs all values in different rows of the column. Code is as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
        With Range("A1")
            lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & lastrow).Value = TextBox1.Value
        End With
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Any suggestions please? your response will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly you want to have each line in the text box in its own row so this would work

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Variant
Dim rowCounter As Long
    rowCounter = 1
    For Each i In Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)
        'start at row 1 column A
        Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = i
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate. Split returns an array that you can use to fill all the rows at once.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Data As Variant

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
    Data = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        If Target.Value <> "" Then Set Target = Target.Offset(1)

        Target.Resize(UBound(Data) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Data)
    End With

    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's exactly what I was trying to do